# Passing array down to component and updating it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
class Main extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {

            loggedIn:false,
            //This is where the user currently is
            pagenum : 0,
            //This is all the steps the user will take
            steps : [{name:'Menu', type:"menu", active:true, completed:false, stepnumber:0},
                    {name:'Step 1', type:"idea01",active:false, completed:false, stepnumber:1},
                    {name:'Step 2', type:"idea02",active:false, completed:false, stepnumber:2},
                    {name:'Step 3', type:"idea03",active:false, completed:false, stepnumber:3}]
        };
    }

moveAlong(to, fro){
            let newArray = [...this.state.steps];
            //updating the step within the new array with the new active variable
            newArray[this.state.pagenum] = {...newArray[this.state.pagenum], active: !newArray[this.state.pagenum].active}
            newArray[fro] = {...newArray[this.state.pagenum], completed: !newArray[this.state.pagenum].completed}
            console.log(...newArray);
            //replacing the previous array with new array with new info
            this.setState({ steps: newArray});    
}

render(){
            return[
                <Sidebar steps={this.state.steps} pageNum={this.state.pagenum}/>
            ...

            ];

        }
    }
```

Once I call moveAlong from a child component, the array in my state gets updated. 
However, the array passed down to the Sidebar component does not get updated within the Sidebar functions..
Any ideas?

TLDR: moveAlong() gets executed but the changes to the array are not reflected downstream to the Sidebar

Edit: Added Sidebar code below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Step from './Step';
import '../styles/style.css';

class Sidebar extends Component {

    //bringing in the array of "steps" from the parent Main
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
         this.state = {
            //storing the array in local state
            pagenum: props.pageNum,
            stepsnodes: props.steps
        };
    }


    render() {

        //shifting the array into a list to be rendered passsing through the step's specifics
        const listItems = this.state.stepsnodes.map((d) => <Step active={d.active} name={d.name} completed={d.completed} stepnumber={d.stepnumber}/>);  
        console.log("Sidebar's arraystatus: " + listItems);
        return(
            <div className ="sidebar">
            {listItems}
            </div>
            );
    }
}

export default Sidebar;
´´´
```

Comment: Can you share more code about your sidebar? I think there is no problem with the code you provided.

Comment: I've created this reproduction, it seems to work: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-tereshkova-sxlcf?file=/src/App.js What are your problems ?

Comment: The problem I encounter is that even though the array gets correctly updated via the moveAlong function, on the Sidebar level, the array remains unchanged therefore the Sidebar UI doesn't update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the steps are loaded into `Sidebar`'s state in it's constructor - so only once at mount time:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
         this.state = {
            //storing the array in local state
            pagenum: props.pageNum,
            stepsnodes: props.steps
        };
    }
```

If you change the render method to use props instead of state it should work

```
const listItems = this.state.stepsnodes.map(..)
// to
const listItems = this.props.stepsnodes.map(..)
```

Comment: Thank you - This solutions works.
Considering I only push `props down` to update the sidebar, is there any use for having anything in the Sidebar's state VS just rendering according to `props` ?

Cheers

Comment: Nope, I'd say you can safely remove the state from `Sidebar`. This blog post from the react team is a bit old but goes into detail on why the pattern of copying props to local state should be avoided https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html